# Are there any Jedi or Sith droids?

Tags: star-wars, droids

In the films, I only saw organic life forms become Jedi or Sith. Were there ever any droids who could use the Force?

Or is that impossible because of the [M-word](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/882/in-the-star-wars-universe-how-are-midichlorians-supposed-to-work)?

Comment: In Star Wars The Old Republic, on Hoth for the Jedi Knight storyline, the player meets with a Jedi who made (or maybe just discovered, I'm not 100% anymore) Force-sensitive droids. She asks for your opinion on the matter (Among the options are stuff along the lines of "That's preposterous" and "This could change everything we know about the Force"), but in the end, I don't think anything is made of it.

Comment: You don't think the Force was with R2D2?  It sure seems like it to me.  He's always "getting lucky" at the last second and saving the heroes.  He can run through two lines of fighters firing blasters at each other, and not get hit.  He gets sold to Anakin's son!  Then he manages to locate Obi-Wan on Tatooine.  So, maybe droids use the Force, but differently than organics?

Comment: From the Legends novels Coruscant Nights and the Last Jedi, the droïd I-Five may be Force sensitive... A bit. At least, he has a Force-signature, which is pretty unique for a droïd. But it's far from being a Jedi.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10505/4918 "Are There Machines That Use the Force?"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Zahn's *Thrawn Trilogy*, Jedi Master C'Boath explains to Luke Skywalker that droids are simply holes in the Force - so, at least as far as c-canon goes, it looks like droids are not capable of tapping the Force.

Comment: Additionally, [Lumiya points out](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lumiya#Force_ability) that neither she nor Darth Vader could become a true master of the force, due to their prosthesis. `However, while unlimited paths to power were made available to and explored by Lumiya, her requisite prosthetic enhancements considerably limited her ability to realize many of them. Thus, while her knowledge of battle meditation and the extremely-effective Sith battle coordination was absolute, she was unable to actually influence combat in that manner, a handicap she attributed to her prostheses.`

Comment: That General Grievous and other droids are unaffected by attempts to use the force to influence them suggests that this answer is also true.  Not only are they unable to wield it, others cannot wield it against them except physically. Do note that this is distinctly different from [force shielding](http://www.comicvine.com/profile/silver2467/blog/force-misconceptions-force-resistant-species/89478/), such as toydarians and huttese have - but that this does lend some thought to the idea that perhaps a droid could be force sensitive while also being resistant to force control.

Comment: I'd like to point out that C'Baoth was, not to put too fine a point to it, *batshit insane*, and according to _Outbound Flight_ he was pretty out there already *before* Clone Derangement set in. Take his statements with a generous helping of salt.

Comment: @AdamDavis I think General Grievous is not entirely a droid, he has a (human?) heart in his chest and human-looking eyes, and I think it's said in the third film that he used to be more human but was saved from death by being implanted in a droid body, or something. I'm speaking from old recollections, so not entirely sure.

Answer (score 33):

As far as canonical sources, I don't believe there's ever been an inorganic Force-sensitive (due to everybody's favorite M-word, as mentioned).

Non-canonically, there's always [Skippy the Jedi Droid](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid)!

[image: Skippy meets R2 who tells him about his mission and 3PO who won't shut up, he has a Force Vision of the events of the original trilogy]

Comment: I really wish I had never even read that summary of Skippy.  Anyone got any brain bleach?

Comment: Note that Skippy was originally created by Peter David as an "Impossible Story" - a story that came to him, but wasn't anything that would ever really see print, that he'd relate in his "But I Digress" column in The Comic Buyer's Guide. It's not the only "Impossible Story" that eventually saw print (I believe *THE LAST AVENGERS STORY* was first seen this same way), but the other notable one I recall is "Quantum Beast", where Sam Beckett (*QUANTUM LEAP*) found himself in the body of Vincent (*BEAUTY AND THE BEAST* TV series from the late 80s/early 90s).

Answer (score 19):

We need some wisdom from Master Yoda on this one:

> My ally is the Force. And a powerful ally it is. It is what gives a Jedi his power. It is the energy field created by all living things. It surrounds us, penetrates us.

And:

> Life creates it, makes it grow. Its energy surrounds us and binds us. Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter.

That seems to make it fairly cut-and-dried: the Force needs life.

Comment: Great - can you please add where these quotes came from (and link to the scripts)?

Comment: @Wikis I believe it's from ESB, during Luke's training.  Not going to look it up just now, though.

Comment: Define "Life"... Specify organic Yoda did not

Comment: Yoda does make a mention of the force existing `You must feel the Force around you; here, between you, me, the tree, the rock, everywhere, yes. Even between the land and the ship` just after what you quote @user8719, which seems to open up some relationship of the force existing in non-organic and "lifeless" objects.

Answer (score 8):

[Shards](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shard) are Force-sensitive inorganic beings that sometimes had droid bodies: [Iron Knight](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Knight).

Answer (score 7):

### No, but perhaps there could be

**To the best  of my knowledge, no Force-sensitive droids have been mentioned in canon**, let alone Jedi or Sith droids. In Legends, there is [Skippy the Jedi Droid](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid), but he was non-canon even back in the old EU days.

As to whether it’s *possible* for a droid to be Force-sensitive, we can’t be sure. **There exists at least one major obstacle to any potential Jedi or Sith droid**. The Force possesses a biological<sup>1</sup> factor: the [midi-chlorians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian):

> Q: What are midi-chlorians?
>
> A: Midi-chlorians are tiny, intelligent life-forms that live inside the cells of all living things in the galaxy. They do no harm, and help their host use the Force.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*</sub>

These entities live inside all living cells. Since droids have no cells, and are constructed from steel, silicon, and various other mechanical and electronic parts, they lack midi-chlorians. As such, **droids have no connection to the Force.** <sup>2</sup>

[image: A droid explains to Vader that the Force is indifferent to them and that is why they don't rule. A woman off to the side says: "True, Droids are dead to the Force. It flows through all life guides us."]

**The droid 0-0-0 proposed a way around this, though, one which might enable a droid to use the Force.** If a droid were specially constructed to contain human blood, the Force could flow through it:

[image: The droid goes on to explain it isn't that droids are not alive that they can't use the Force, it's because they have no blood. A purpose built droid with blood should be Force-sensitive.]

As such, while the average “droid on the street” could not be Force-sensitive, a purpose-built one might be.

It’s important to take this suggestion with several grains of salt, though:

1. It’s untested. It’s hard to know what would happen if it were implemented. Would the midi-chlorians care? The Force? Maybe, maybe not. Even if they both had no problem with a Force-sensitive droid, mass production might still fail.
2. Vader dismissed it out of hand.
3. The droid that thought of it was a psychotic [torture technician](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TortureTechnician) with no particular expertise in the Force.

<sub>1: There’s clearly a little more going on with the Force than mere biology. While the Force *can* be inherited (Luke and Anakin; Talzin, Maul and Savage Opress), this doesn’t usually seem to be the case. Force-sensitive people pop up, not only with with no Force-sensitive relatives, but quite possibly no Force-sensitives on their entire planet (don’t forget, there were only 10,000 Jedi). It’s not at all clear that the opposite (Force sensitives having Force-sensitive children) is that reliable, either. Don’t forget, Force sensitivity comes from a mystical energy field and magical, intelligent symbiotes.</sub>

<sub>2: *Darth Vader 18*</sub>

Comment: Nice answer! Can you please add a reference for *"Vader dismissed it out of hand."?*

Answer (score 4):

I just found out in [*Star Wars Saga Edition*](http://www.theberserker.net/berserker/sw/rule_books/SW_Saga_Edition_Core_Rulebook.pdf) that at level 3, player droid characters may generate an Independent Droid Class which may produce a "Force" effect of up to 5 points.

MagnaGuards also possess a small amount of "Force" power (a default position of 1 point).

[image: Screenshot of the abilities of a IG-100 Series MagnaGuard; it lists various details and Force is set to 1]

Answer (score 4):

No droid in and of itself was able to use the Force. However, there were droids that made use of biological components that were able to use the force in some way. Specifically in the no longer canon (sorry EU/Legends) book [*The Cestus Deception*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cestus_Deception) ["Bio-Droids"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/JK-13_security_droid) make use of an unusually Force-sensitive creature called a Dashta Eel granting them combat capabilities almost on par with Jedi.

Comment: Nice find +1. Welcome to SFF.SE.

Answer (score 3):

Shards are droid with the Force:

> Shards were a silicon-based species native to the planet Orax, who took the form of irregularly faceted cylindrical crystals thirty to forty centimeters in length. Faint pulses of light—thought signals propagating through their "brains"—could be seen inside their bodies. Shards were immobile in their natural state, but could be installed in specially modified droids.
>
> <sub>[Star Wars Wiki, Shard](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shard)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Since droids are not considered living things, the force most likely won't exist with them. But the way technology is in the Star Wars universe, I can easily see a droid use technology to imitate the results of using the force. Like force lightning could be imitated by using an Arc Emitter to shoot and direct bolts of lightning. An electromagnetic field or something like that can imitate the telekinetic form of the force.

Comment: Doing something effectively similar to the Force is not the same as using the Force - just as wielding a lightsaber (or four) does not make Grievious a Jedi/Sith.

Answer (score 1):

In the original trilogy during Luke's training with Yoda, Yoda does tell Luke that all life creates the force but in the same breath he throws a monkey wrench into it and says rocks create the force.

Droids are technically living beings they have personalities and various mannerisms though programmed into them they do want to preserve themselves when endangered as is typical of any living being the only difference between a human/ alien and a droid is that droids are mass produced.

In S.W. K.o.t.O.R. wearing any armor restricts the type of force powers you can use, like Darth Vader and his prosthetic limbs being unable to create blue force lightning but it doesn't say that he can't use other offensive force abilities I.E. force choke or telekinesis.

Droids are living but they are different type of life form they are artificial.