# Can any species produce a Force-Sensitive?

Tags: star-wars

Given that [droids apparently cannot become Jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/are-there-any-jedi-or-sith-droids), I wonder if every intelligent biological species is capable of producing beings that are Force-Sensitive?

Or are there some species characteristics that can make it 100% impossible for them ever to produce a Force-sensitive individual.

<sub>NOTE: Let's exclude - if they exist in EU - things like random new-species-creating mutations - e.g. the individual should be 100% the same species, able to interbreed.</sub>

Comment: Hah! After posting this I realised, [there's that word again](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-should-we-handle-any-list-questions).

Comment: So, you're not following yourself?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: I just raised the question, I haven't answered it myself, yet. ;)

Comment: Behold Darth Kermit, Dark Lord of the Sith!

Comment: I made this a bit more precise (I hope), feel free to roll back if you don't agree with the changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only force-sensitive individuals could become Jedi. The species listed below have all been demonstrated to be force-sensitive; consistently producing force-sensitive individuals with the potential to become Jedi. Individuals of other species have been force-sensitive, and become Jedi; but there are many species which have never produced any Jedi.

From [wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_sensitivity#Species_and_objects):

> Species with high number of Force-sensitives included Humans, Kel Dors, Ithorians, Twi'leks, Zabraks, Nautolans, and even the rare and mysterious Duinuogwuins. Species producing low number of Force-sensitives included the Wookiees, Hutts and Caamasi. The Neti, Red Sith and Miraluka were entirely composed of Force-sensitives. Gotals may all have possessed the ability to sense the Force, although they had little practical use for it. Felucians, as a species, were all Force-sensitive, but none were known to have become Jedi.

Comment: In particular, the Yuuzhan Vong were completely force-immune and would probably therefore not be able to become Jedi.

Comment: @Plutor: You obviously haven't read the end of the New Jedi Order series.

Comment: I think he's more asking whether or not it's possible for any intelligent biological species to have force-sensitive individuals.

Comment: -1 - Sorry, but I don't think this answers the question at all. He's asking for either a specific in-universe rule stating that ANY intelligent biological species CAN become force sensitive, or a very explicit in-universe example of one that is stated to be 100% unable to produce a Force-sensitive individual. Frequency doesn't count

Comment: There is a Sith pureblood in the *Star Wars: The Old Republic* game who is not Force-sensitive. In fact, there's a list of [non-Force-sensitive Red Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Non-Force-sensitive_Sith)

Answer (score 5):

The Yuuzhan Vong are a race from outside the Star Wars galaxy, and do not have midichlorians as part of their biology, in contrast to all life within the Star Wars galaxy. As such, they are neither Force-sensitive, nor even affected by the Force. So, there is no natural way for a Yuuzhan Vong to become a Jedi or Sith; I'm sure somewhere in the Extended Universe there is a Yuuzhan Vong who acquired Force powers artificially through infusion of midichlorians, but there are no natural-born Yuuzhan Vong Force-sensitives.

Other than that, there is no rule in the Star Wars universe I am aware of that any specific race cannot produce Force-sensitives. It may be more or less rare among a particular race; there is, for instance, only one known Gungan Force-sensitive (a Sith whose name has been lost to time). Other species, like Felucians, are all Force-sensitive.

Comment: When you say "not affected by the Force", could Vadar still choke them out?

Comment: The exact physics behind the Force haven't been quite that thoroughly explained AFAIK. We know it's an energy field generated by all living things within the Star Wars galaxy. We also know it can affect non-living things such as Luke's lightsaber (or random rocks, boxes, pipes etc). So, whether a Yuuzhan Vong could be pushed/pulled/choked depends on whether their physical makeup is something that Force energies can interact with; they might appear as inanimate matter, or being composed of matter from outside the galaxy they might sidestep the Force entirely.