# Are There Machines That Use the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

I've noticed there are actually non-Force-sensitive Jedi (or at least one, Randon), and that Droids are described as "holes in the force" (cited on our own site, [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/are-there-any-jedi-or-sith-droids)).

But are there machines in the Star Wars universe that are able to make use of the Force in some way?

Comment: Frak! [Any](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-should-we-handle-any-list-questions) ... *[again](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/can-any-species-become-a-jedi)!*

Comment: @Wikis - this is not an "any" question but a "[yes/no](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/are-questions-looking-to-simply-prove-or-disprove-a-premise-with-a-yes-no-answer)" question - as per Meta, it was decided to be quite on-topic. Also, would you mind explicitly stating the negative effect on the site from this specific question and its answers? (aside from reminding me of Skippy the Droid, which should quilify as grounds for blowing up offender's planet)

Comment: @DVK: It *is* an any question, at least according to the title! But it is not a list question, I agree (though I not see where that is *agreed* on meta). I don't see anything negative at all here. My comment including another any question *which I created around the same time*, simply to illustrate how easily it is done. Personally, I'm all for any questions!

Comment: @DVK: removing the word any doesn't change the nature of the question. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Rakatan Infinite Empire](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rakata) used several:

- **Hyperdrives**:

  > Rakata used **Force-based hyperdrives** that allowed their vessels to journey to worlds **with a strong Force signature**
- **[Star Forge](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_forge)**

  > The Star Forge was a giant automated shipyard, designed to create the most powerful army of all time, constructed by the Rakatan Infinite Empire in 30,000 BBY, five thousand years before the rise of the Galactic Republic. The Star Forge drew energy and matter from a nearby star which, **when combined with the power of the Force**, was capable of creating an endless supply of ships, droids, and other war material.
  >   ...
  >   ... the Star Forge began feeding off these negative traits inherent in its creators. As a result the **Star Forge became an immense tool of dark side power**.
- **[Star Maps](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Maps)**, mentioned by Wikis's answer

  > Constructed of a self-sustaining technology that **was imbued with and drew upon the dark side of the Force**...

Answer (score 12):

Well, I don't know if this counts but there is a [Force Detector](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_detector). But, as the name suggests, it *detects* the Force rather than *uses* it.

[image: Force Detector]

There are many *[force **sensitive** objects](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Force-sensitive_objects)*. At least two of these are said to be *"imbued with"* the force, which I guess implies some kind of *using* of the force:

> The **[Star Map](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Map):** *Constructed of a self-sustaining technology that was **imbued with and drew upon the dark side of the Force**, these Star Maps were fabricated to be monuments to the glory of the Rakatan Empire.*

[image: The Star Map]

> The **[Stone Mirror](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stone_mirror):** 
>   *The stone mirror was **a Force-imbued object**...[which] the Tulgah witch used the mirror to witness events that were happening outside of her fortress.*

[image: The Stone Mirror]

Comment: Please remove the Force Detector. It detects not the Force, but Force-sensitive individuals - basically, Midichlorian counter, ala Qui-Gon in The Phantom Menace, just at a distance

Comment: @DVK: from [Wookipedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_detector): *"A Force detector or Jedi reader was a device used by Emperor Palpatine's Jedi hunters to identify Force-sensitive individuals. It consisted of two sheet crystal paddles connected to a control pack powered by rare thaissen crystals found only on Mimban. When an individual was placed between the paddles, the device would produce a hologram of the person in question. If the individual was Force sensitive, a blue corona would surround the hologram."* I think this is a **different device** to the Midichlorian counter.

Comment: @DVK: plus, I think what you are calling a Midichlorian counter was actually just a [blood test](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian#Study_and_analysis).

Comment: correct, it's a different device. But it serves the same PURPOSE (e.g. detect midichlorian count - as opopsed to Force)

Comment: @DVK: are you sure it detects **midichlorian count**? I haven't read that.

Comment: Not sure, but that seems the likeliest implication based that it detects Force-sensitives. A Force-sensitive may not necessarily be manipulating the Force at any given time (either too weak, too untrained, or backwards, trained enough not to bother projecting, ala Yoda/Mara Jade). So to reliably detecting a Force Sensitive, you need to detect midichlorians.

Answer (score 9):

There was this R5 unit who had the Force: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid

Comment: Ah, yes, [Skippy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8081/are-there-any-jedi-or-sith-droids/8082#8082)...

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

There are a variety of such devices in the current canon.

### Holocrons

Holocrons use the Force for information security.

> Most of the data contained on a holocron is related to the nature and
>   applications of the Force, so sharing this knowledge outside the Jedi
>   Order is discouraged. For this reason, many holocrons are constructed
>   with a security mechanism that permits access only to those who
>   exhibit Force sensitivity.
>
> <sub>*Ultimate Star Wars*</sub>

And, lest we assume that this is a mere mundane measurement of midi-chlorian count, there are other holocrons that only permit access to those strong in the dark side:

> Similar to Jedi holocrons, Sith holocrons are often accessible only to
>   those who can control the dark side of the Force.
>
> <sub>*Ultimate Star Wars*</sub>

### Kyber crystals

First, kyber crystals themselves are attuned to the Force.

> Kyber crystals are rare, naturally occurring gems found on scattered
>   planets across the galaxy. They concentrate energy in a unique manner
>   and resonate with the Force.
>
> <sub>*Ultimate Star Wars*</sub>

Besides this, of course, their connection to the Force apparently renders them difficult to perceive to all but their destined bearer (or perhaps creates some special perceptual cue for such individuals):

> From time to time, someone would arrive and call to them, like the
>   harmony of a perfect song. Each crystal had a chosen bearer, and only
>   that bearer would hear the music and see the glow. All others would
>   pass by, seeing nothing but more ice.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

Lightsabers can be considered to use the Force, since the crystal within can help Jedi concentrate in battle. [According to the Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/lightsaber-crystal):

> Because Jedi let the Force guide their selection of the crystal, the
>   vibration that the crystal creates in the lightsaber blade helps Jedi
>   center themselves and find balance in the Force. In this way, a Jedi
>   can center his or her attention beyond the distractions of combat.

In light of the previous information, it seems very likely that the energy of a kyber crystal itself comes from its resonance with the Force, and thus that anything that uses a kyber crystal to focus or concentrate its energy, such as the Death Star or Starkiller base, is a machine that employs the Force.

### Other

In addition, in *Darth Vader 18* the droid 0-0-0 proposed, *very* speculatively, that a droid with a special engine that employed human blood might be able to use the Force. Whether this is the case has not been confirmed, and whether a thinking entity such as a droid counts as a machine is unclear in any case.

Comment: If Kyber crystals use the force, then you can add the death star to your list.

Comment: Kyber crystals are not machines.

Comment: @PmanAce - That's why I referred to machines built with kyber crystals.

Answer (score 2):

There are weapons in the universe that draw upon Force energies. The [Dark Reaper](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Reaper) and its companion [Force Harvester](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_Harvester), for instance.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In Legends, the iron knights were a species of sentient crystals known as the Shard. While they themselves were not machines, they were placed in robotic bodies. Their machine bodies were capable of channeling the Force through the influence of the Shard in the center. In a way, the Shard acted as something of a main battery for their droid hosts, essentially allowing them to wield the Force. 
For the full story, here's the link to the Wookieepedia article.
https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Knight

Comment: Do you have a source?

Answer (score -2):

There is droid whelding "sith" like general grevious bu he actually is a cyborg so that means cyborgs count as human but doids are robots not having any life there being no forcesenitivity.

Comment: Grievious is neither a Sith or a Force wielder. He simply owns and uses lightsabers.

Comment: Grievous isn't Force-sensitive or capable of using the Force in any way. He happens to wield lightsabers in combat and with his advanced machine body, is capable of mimicking some of the reflexes of a Force user. But he is pretty helpless against a Force user who decides to use Force techniques against him (which leaves one to wonder why the Jedi that fight him simply don't Force Push him into oblivion).