# Does the Force act like God in Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars

Has the Force ever acted on its own or as a deity in Star Wars canon?

Comment: Hey guys, three close votes and no explanation. Can we fix that please?

Comment: What's to fix? This question is highly subjective and open to interpretation. I was under the impression we stayed away from religion overall. Since the Force acts through a biological means it surely couldn't be construed as the Almighty Creator of the Universe in the religious sense could it? I felt the question was inappropriate for this forum. My opinion, nothing more.

Comment: That said, if the religious parts were cut out and the "has it ever acted on its own" part left in, I'd vote to reopen.  Nick's answer is a pretty good one.

Comment: Vote to reopen. The question is very clear and I think it is on topic, as the accepted answer shows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9715/2136) by DavRob60 on the question of Anakin's father.

> There is a recently published book, *Star Wars: Darth Plagueis*, that supposedly answer this question. From Anakin Skywalker Wookieepedia article
>
> In addition, although Darth Plagueis did attempt to influence the midichlorians to create the ultimate Sith weapon alongside Darth Sidious, the experiment was ultimately a failure, and the midichlorians, sensing the Sith's inherent malevolent intention, not only refused to do so, but in retaliation, conceived Anakin Skywalker in order to destroy the Sith once and for all.

It appears that the force (or at least the midi-chlorains) acted in a Deity-like fashion to create Anakin Skywalker.

Comment: Then this must be the only god [that has its own measuring device](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10505/are-there-machines-that-use-the-force/10506#10506).

Comment: @Wikis *cough* e-meter *cough*

Comment: I always thought that (from Obi-wan's description) the Force could best be thought of as a 'collective unconsciousness' - it has no will, except in that it's the extension of the will of all beings that are part of it; hence the occasional actions/choices it seems to make.  In effect, it (via the midichlorians) just channels the will/desires of the living, force related, members of the universe at large.

Answer (score 2):

The force is a mystical energy field that surrounds everything and everyone in the universe. It has no consciousness and takes no action.

The force is more like a force of nature than a diety.

Therefore the Jedi/Sith and all other force sensitive beings who try to understand it are less like priests and more like researchers, but due to the metaphysic nature of the force doing so requires a spiritual mindset.

Answer (score -1):

No. The Force has never acted on its own or as a deity in Star Wars canon.

Comment: Didn't the force create Anakin?

Comment: Probably the midichlorians created him. Or whatever you call those foul little abominable "explanations for the source of the force" that completely ruined the supreme coolness of Star Wars just as surely as Jar Jar Binks.