# Which Force-sensitive species in the Star Wars Galaxy have never produced a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I was reading [this thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/can-any-species-produce-a-force-sensitive) regarding whether any species can produce Force-sensitive beings, and it lead me to wonder a related and (hopefully) separate question: Are there any species in the Star Wars Galaxy that, even though they produce Force-sensitive beings, have never produced a Jedi, particularly "well-known" species?

The Wookieepedia article mentions one, the [Jungle Felucians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jungle_Felucian), and another example I'd imagine would be [the Sith species themselves](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_(species)), they are a well-known species in Legends, producing lots of dark side users, but did they ever produce a Jedi?

Which other well-known, or not, Force-sensitive species have never produced a Jedi?

Answers can be from Legends or Canon.

Comment: That depends what you mean exactly by 'Jedi': the name itself designates one of the numerous Force-sects that popped up in early galactic history and who managed to establish dominance by absorbing most of the others, then it passed on the language to designate the users of the Light-Side during the wars with various Sith and Dark Side Empires, before finally becoming synonymous with 'Force-user' at the time of the original trilogy.

Comment: @Valorum Do you have any suggestions about how I can further differentiate this question from the one it is assessed to be a duplicate of?