# What happened to the R5-D4 from A New Hope?

Tags: star-wars, droids

The R5 astromech that Owen Lars initally bought (Luke calls it an R2 unit but later sources classify the droid as an R5 model) with the faulty motivator- was it ever repaired and/or sold to another party? Was it still in the possession of the jawas when the stormtroopers tracked them down?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8082/1234

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no Canon record of what happened to him. However, he has further adventures in the Legends Canon.

From [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R5-D4):

> After failing to make a sale, the Squib trader Macemillian-winduarté stole R5-D4 from the Jawas, saving the droid from destruction at the hands of stormtroopers. R5-D4 then changed hands once again in Mos Eisley, being sold to Voren Na'al, Rebel Alliance historian and spy. While communicating with the droid through a datapad, Na'al learned a great deal about the sale of R2-D2 and C-3PO to Owen Lars. Na'al then refurbished the maltreated droid and installed an intelligence gathering software package. Decades of low self-confidence and jealousy were reversed: R5-D4 had a purpose. R5-D4 was placed as an intelligence gathering source in the office of the Imperial Prefect's administrative assistant in Mos Eisley. He continued to serve in that capacity, providing important and valuable data to the Alliance, until the Battle of Endor.

Answer (score 1):

In the penultimate episode of *the Book of Boba Fett* I saw a white R5-astromech with red striping in the possession of the ship mechanic Peli Motto.

A little digging on Wookiepedia did confirm that this droid was the same [R5-unit](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R5-D4) Owen Lars originally purchased in *A New Hope*.

> Sometime later, R5 was acquired by Peli Motto, and once again crossed paths with Din Djarin in the Mos Eisley spaceport

Comment: Hmm. I couldn't find any specific confirmation that this is the same r5 unit. He's referred to as "R5" in the show, but not by his full designation