# Widespread religions at the time of The Galactic Civil War

Tags: star-wars, religion

Were there any active, widespread, common, public religions in the Star Wars galaxy at the time of the rebel alliance?  If so, what were they?

By widespread, I mean religions that span multiple systems, and aren't just tied to one specific world.  All of the examples that I'm aware of are either small cults, or specifically tied to individual worlds.  By common (and public) I mean that most educated/worldly people in the relevant sector(s) would have heard of the religion.

Note that, by this time, the Jedi are considered to be extinct, and the other explicitly Force based belief systems, including the Sith, are a combination of small-scale and secretive.

If there are so many, that this would turn into a list question, I really only care about the one (or two) most common religions that Outer Rim.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/do-heaven-and-hell-exist-in-star-wars?

Comment: @DVK No (IMHO) -- that is about specific religious beliefs; this is about religious organizations (or groups if they're only loosely organized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Star Wars galaxy doesn't appear to have any widespread, common belief systems, beyond that of The Force. And even then, most people only have a vague concept of The Force without knowing much about it.

Instead, it was most common for each world to have its own popular religion, with the inhabitants of that world practicing the religion regardless of their actual location. Many worlds were polytheistic, with the inhabitants worshipping one or more gods (similar to a Greek or Roman system of gods). Others were monotheistic, while still others leaned more towards philosophy rather than worship of any deity.

There WERE, however, a few religious organizations that spread themselves across the galaxy and could therefore be found across many systems, or otherwise had a widespread influence on the galaxy. Here are a couple of examples:

- The [Order of the Ffib](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Ffib) - the Ffib order of priests had missionaries on numerous planets throughout the galaxy, and were common enough that many people had heard of the Order.
- The [B'omarr Order](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/B%27omarr_Order) - while their religion itself was not widespread, the temples built by the B'omarr monks became a favorite of the Hutts. B'omarr monasteries can be found on several planets throughout the Outer Rim. In addition, the Hutts adopted the same architectural style and many buildings inspired by the B'omarr can be found on Nal Hutta.

The [Star Wars wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Religions) has articles on numerous religions & religious organizations found in the SW galaxy. It's probably the best place to browse if you're looking for more detail.

Comment: Thanks, the wiki doesn't let me filter on size or time-frame, so rather than wade through all the entries there, I asked here.

Comment: @Dave, most of what you're looking for will be under the "Religious Organizations" sub-category on that wiki page I linked.