# Does the concept of heaven exist in the galaxy far, far away?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, religion, the-empire-strikes-back

In Star Wars - *Episode V:  The Empire Strikes Back*, when Han is being urged not to go looking for Luke on Hoth, we hear this exchange:

> RANDOM <del>JERK</del> REBEL GUY:  Your Tauntaun will freeze before you reach the first marker!
>
> HAN SOLO:  **Then I'll see you in hell!**

This clearly implies that people in the galaxy far, far away are familiar with the concept of hell.  Is there any evidence that they also have some concept of heaven?  I'm especially interested in the movies, but any source would do (although I would prefer a canonical source, Legends would be acceptable if nothing else is available).

Comment: -1 for striking out 'Jerk' ;)

Comment: Just saw [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/do-heaven-and-hell-exist-in-star-wars?rq=1) over there ->  Possible dupe?  Don't mean to answer then mark as dupe, but I saw that question *after* I answered!

Comment: @N_Soong I saw it just before you commented, and I VTCed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wookieepedia says that in *[Star Wars 10: Behemoth from the World Below](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_10:_Behemoth_from_the_World_Below)*, the following expression is used by [Lepi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lepi):

> **Heavenly** hutches

So, it looks as though indeed it is used.

[This Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_phrases_and_slang/Legends#H) says the following:

> Heaven: A place of joy and rest.

but unfortunately it provides no source so I'm not inclined to accept it as a valid instance.

Comment: I found a few specific Legends references to belief in a paradise-like afterlife elsewhere on wookieepedia and put it as an answer to the other question, see [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113898/22250).