# Is the Force magic?

Tags: star-wars, magic, the-force

I think that the Jedi refuse to call it such, but they can be considered biased opinion. There certainly exist Sith magic, but it seems to be considered separate from the usual Sith powers, although they all draw from the same dark side.

What is the nature of the Force in relation to what is commonly considered magic? Looking for both in and out of universe interpretations.

Comment: Are you asking about "magic" as the term is used in our galaxy, or as it's used in the fictional galaxy with Jedi and Sith in it?

Comment: Kind of an opinion based question dont you think? There is no real answer, we know what the force is. "Magic" is such a broad term and there is no singular definition.

Comment: I think it has to be opinion-based. Ask a true Star Wars fan and they'd probably shout "Absolutely not!" Ask a casual cinemagoer and they'd tell you The Force, HP wizard magic and any special skill in anything are *obviously* all magic exactly the same as each other.

Comment: Sith *magic* doesn't really exist either, what *does* exist is Sith *Alchemy*, which I understood as using *The Force* as a tool for changes made to bascially anything (materials, plants, animals, people, etc.). Using the Force is manipulating an energy field, kinda like using magnetism. Is that magic -- to the primitive and uninitiated (yes I am talking to you, teddy bears living on Endor's moon) it can appear thus. So can the fact that a plane flies instead of a droid. Star Wars may be a Space *fantasy*, but *magic* in that sense, no. Well the Aing-Tii do pretty weird stuff, so, who knows...

Comment: It's not magic, it's [science](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/882/in-the-star-wars-universe-how-are-midichlorians-supposed-to-work) (cough, cough).

Answer (score 3):

***In-universe***, it would seem that, at least around the time of the Battle of Yavin, the Force was considered as somewhat of a folktale, a religion, or a bunch of parlour tricks.

Consider Admiral Motti's view, before he knew better:

> Don't try to frighten us with your sorcerer's ways, Lord Vader. Your sad devotion to that ancient religion has not helped you conjure up the stolen data tapes, or given you clairvoyance enough to find the rebels' hidden fort... (choking noises)

And consider Han Solo's stance on it:

> Hokey religions and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid.
>   (...)
>   Kid, I've flown from one side of this galaxy to the other. I've seen a lot of strange stuff, but I've never seen anything to make me believe there's one all-powerful Force controlling everything. There's no mystical energy field that controls my destiny. It's all a lot of simple tricks and nonsense.